# ETH0 no address ip with ifconfig

Tags: ifconfig, ipv4, lxd

I've created a new LXC on debian jessie, but it doesn't have an ipv4 address. When I connect to my LXC and do ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr blabla
          inet6 addr: blabla/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: blabla/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:81 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10368 (10.1 KiB)  TX bytes:9480 (9.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

As you can see, I have no inet addr in the eth0. I've tried to restart the networking service, but nothing has changed. How can I get an address?

I even tried:

```
lxc test stop 
lxc network attach lxdbr0 test eth0 eth0
lxc config device set test eth0 ipv4.address 10.99.10.42
lxc start test
```

But nothing

Thanks

Comment: I edited the tags: the command `lxc` is actually meaning the container is running with LXD (which uses LXC as backend).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Service restart NetworkManager
```

Or :

```
Service restart network-manager
```

Then go to the internet settings and find eth0 and select it to access anything you connect to your computer via Ethernet cable

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunatly, it doesn't work. I tried: `service network-manager restart` and `service NetworkManager restart` but the output is the same: `Failed to restart NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

Comment: Ok then try this :   $apt-get install network-manager      And then reboot your computer and also : What do you see in network settings ? Can you send a screenshot ? Do you see Any Ethernet connections there??

Comment: How can I see my network settings? I put my ifconfig in my questions, isn't it this? I tried your answer but it didn't worked. I got `Err http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libnewt0.52 amd64 0.52.17-1+b1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
`, and like 50 lines like this

Comment: Yes I actually use kali where you can see network settings in the toolbar you have to specify the Linux distro you have installed but I think in most of them you can see the WiFi icon in the toolbar (or taskbar whatever) and click it to see all available internet connections (wired or wireless)

Comment: The thing is I'm on an LXC, on debian jessie, and I want my LXC to have an ipv4 address, I only have an ipv6. For every other LXC I have (5 others), all of them have ipv4 and ipv6. I don't know why it's not working on this one